# reference a cell but keep formatting of text from source cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with some text in it. 
Say cell A1.

This text is formatted in a certain way - First few words are bold, line breaks, varying font size, etc

When I reference this cell, say in cell B1:

```
=A1
```

In B1 I just get a long string of text that has none of the formatting that is present on A1

Is there a way to reference and keep the formatting?

I can use format painter and it will recognise the line breaks within the cell, but aspects like the partially bold writing are still not recognised.

Comment: Generally speaking, **no**, formulas can't pick-up formatting.

Comment: If you are willing to manually use format painter on your cell `B1`, would you be willing to manually copy and paste? That would keep all the formatting. Or use a `Worksheet_Change()` event to launch a macro which copies and pastes `A1` to `B1`? That way, whenever the text formatting etc. content of `A1` is changed, `B1` updates with *everything*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
Private changing As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Target.Address = [A1].Address Or changing Then Exit Sub
    changing = True
    [A1].Copy [B1]
    changing = False

End Sub
```

The code above means that whenever any change is made to cell `A1` (*specifically* `A1` - that way the code doesn't execute *every* time a change is made on your sheet - doing that would slow everything down), whatever's in `A1` is copied to `B2`

***Usage***

---

To use, simply

- Right click on the name of your sheet (a tab along the bottom), and select "view code"
- Paste the code in
- Change any cell references to the ones you want (ie replace`[A1]` with `[A3]` or `[A1:A4]` or `[blah]` (i.e. a named cell/range) depending on what you need)
- Close the window. To save the workbook you'll have to save as .xlsm or .xlb if you want to keep the macro

***Notes***

---

- `[A1]` is shorthand for `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range ("A1")`. Typically I would advise against using it as `ActiveSheet` means that if the code ran on *any* sheet in `ThisWorkbook`, it would copy and paste over the `A1` and `B1` of *that sheet*, whereas you probably only want the specific cells on a specific sheet.

  - However in this case, the code only applies to 1 sheet so that's not a problem.
- All the `changing` stuff is necessary because copy/paste triggers a change event; i.e. the macro triggers itself over and over until Excel stops it - not ideal! The `changing` variable which I declare simply acts as a signal to stop the program executing itself.

Comment: Rather than `changing` use `Application.EnableEvents = False` & `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Whilst that is an option, I actually find this method preferable; by using `changing` flags you don't interfere with other parts of your code which you actually care about, and for which you may want events to be enabled.

Comment: I can't see how it would interfere if you disable it on the line before the copy and reenable it on the line after the copy.  There's no other events that would happen in that small timescale that I can think of.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I think the pertinent phrase is **"I can think of"**. Turning off events is _probably_ okay, but you would have to consider every eventuality to be certain that you aren't messing up. With the `changing` method you can be certain it won't interfere with other code as it is totally self contained. That's why I prefer it, although as I say, or this example at least, either would be fine.

Comment: An example where `changing` _would_ be preferable though, is with a `Worksheet_Calculate` event. If your change event triggers an `Activesheet.calculate`, then under an `eventsenabled = False` setup, the `Worksheet_Calculate` event _is not triggered_ (even if you want it to be), whereas the `changing` setup only disables the `Worksheet_Change` from re-triggering, the `Calculate` event would work as normal. Then, if the `Calculate` event _itself_ triggers a `Worksheet_Change`, the `Worksheet_Change` event will be disabled by "`If changing Then Exit Sub`" to prevent looping.

Comment: This work to serve my particular purpose here, thanks.

Comment: Just realised I didn't debug this fully; under some circumstances (specifically when `Target.**Value** = [A1].Value`), you can trick the macro into copying `A1` to `B1` without correct formatting. I should've been testing addresses, not values - code fixed to solve this.