# How to reference many text-filled cells and have ALL the formatting copy too?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote an essay first, but whittled down to this:
I've got **a lot** of data, and need to be able to have my Vlookup functions copy over the formatting as well as the text itself.

I found this from the "Similar Questions" list: [reference a cell but keep formatting of text from source cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486765/reference-a-cell-but-keep-formatting-of-text-from-source-cell) which included this code snippet:

```
Private changing As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Target.Address = [A1].Address Or changing Then Exit Sub
changing = True
[A1].Copy [B1]
changing = False

End Sub
```

Now, that actually looks like it will work for me. But, I need a way of having it check one of 24 cells on my receiving sheet, and copy over the contents of the correct source cell (of 3500+ rows by 60+ columns) on the source sheet. Right now, the source cells are found using VLookup; but how can I tie the macro above to check the correct source cells? I could make 24 copies of the above snippet, one for each destination cell, I think that would work as far as checking the destination cells only when they're changed is concerned, but the B1 reference in the snippet won't work, because the source cell changes with each entry.

Simply: I'm not good at VBA and don't know how to use VLookup and the above snippet together.

Thanks for your ideas!

---

edit: I was asked for more details on how the source data is being found. I have a printable page with four drop-down lists (they use Validation against the Title column of the database) that let me pick (separately) four of the entries from my database. Those selections then trigger VLookups that port in the relevant data from the database into the printing page. The database is 3556 rows by 60 columns, only 17 of which are pulled to the printing page.

Most of these datapoints are pulled over just fine. Setting the destination cell to "Shrink to fit" is sufficient to make sure the data, well, *fits*. For five of these, however, "Shrink to fit" is unavailable, as they are (usually) multi-line entries, and so "Wrap text" must be on, which makes "Shrink to fit" unavailable. This means I must manually fit in the text of those 5 datapoints, for each of the four selections on my print page. This can get quite time-consuming, especially when I have a hundred or more to print off.

Alternatively, as I have mostly done this already, I could manually edit each original entry (setting the column widths and font the same as the print page), and, once they have been made to fit, they could be copied whole to the destination cells on the print page.

So, ideally, the code proposed above could be mashed to check when each of the various 24 cells (they are not continuous) are changed, and then to find the correct source cell (each cell that changes would only ever receive data from a cell in a particular column, so, for example, H5, H77, H149, and H221 will always receive their data from column CD in the database, whereas V5, V77, V149, and V221 will always receive their data from column BZ in the database) and copy over the source data (including all text formatting).

---

edit 2: [A link to my spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VWWK_R-c2tNGojrf6MprTDEMfq1oT9S2). Should've done that to begin with... :p

Answer (score 0):

Like this using a loop (based on your posted code):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:A24"))
    'Any changes in the range of interest?
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False  'suspend event handling
        'Loop over the changed cells...
        For each c in rng.cells
            ProcessChange c '<< handle any lookups
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'restore event handling
    End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: your posted workbook doesn't help much because it's too complex for me to spend time figuring it out, but here's a general approach which should give you a framework for how to look up matches and copy information/formatting from your "listing" sheet.

```
'called for each changed cell
Sub ProcessChange(c As Range)

    Dim m, shtLookup As Workbook, valueCell As Range

    Set shtLookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

    'find the new value in the lookup sheet (in the first column)
    Set m = Application.Match(c.Value, shtLookup.Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then

        'got a match: get the corresponding cell from col CD
        Set valueCell = shtLookup.Range("CD:CD").Cells(m)

        'do something with this cell
        With c.Offset(5, 5) '<< some place relative to the changed cell
            .Value = valueCell.Value   'copy value
            .Width = valueCell.Width   'copy width
            .Height = valueCell.Height 'copy height
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "no match for '" & c.Value & "'"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited my post to provide further details into how the print page picks the items to be printed from the database. I have a Google Sheets copy of the database, if that will help.
It seems to me that the code you wrote would check a defined range (my destination cells are not contiguous) and copy over from literally a few columns over (my source cells are also not contiguous, though they are all in the same column, and they are in a different tab besides). I'm ok having many macros run concurrently, one for each destination, but they need to pick the correct row from the source.

Comment: `Me.Range("A1:A24")` could just as easily be `Me.Range("A1,A5,A10,A15,A20")`  Even after reading your update I'm still not so crear on what you need to do so screenshots or a shared workbook would be a big help.

Comment: If your "database" sheet has formatted data then you could consider copying cells as pictures, then pasting those onto your "print" sheet in the required position.  Then you'll get the exact formatting.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I've added a link to the spreadsheet. I've tried referencing the source cells as images, which does indeed copy over the data with formatting intact. Unfortunately, the destination cells are all different heights, which means the data winds up being stretched or squished (vertically).

The `Me.Range` adjustment you posted makes sense, but I'm still struggling to find a way to adjust the source cell based on the row chosen from the VLookup.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! I was able to make sense of that (woe my insufficient skills), and should be able to run forward. Sorry the spreadsheet didn't help. Thanks again!